Problemas con la selección de múltiples Listbox al mismo tiempo en Tkinter Python
Tengo un codigo en python usando Tkinter pero en la ventana 2 tengo dos ListBox y cuando intento seleccionar opciones de ambas al mismo tiempo no me deja, solo selecciona las opciones de una de ellas y de la otra quita mis selecciones, quiero saber si es problema de mi código, o tengo que hacer alguna configuración para que se queden ambas selecciones de ambos Listbox al mismo tiempo, eh intentando configurar su estado, y probar con un código más sencillo pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema
class VentanaPublico:
    def __init__(self,VentanaPrincipal):
        super().__init__()
        self.ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(VentanaPrincipal)
        self.ventana2.title("Ventana Ingreso Publico")
        self.ventana2.geometry("500x600")
        self.Ventana_Principal = VentanaPrincipal

        

######################################################################################
################################ESPACIOS PARA LOS ELEMENTOS###########################

        
        
        #Cuadro de texto para mostrar las claves o procedimientos encontrados
        self.scroll1 = tk.Scrollbar(self.ventana2, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.listaDatosPublico = tk.Listbox(self.ventana2, width=30, height=4, yscrollcommand=self.scroll1.set,
                                            selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
        self.scroll1.configure(command=self.listaDatosPublico.yview)                 
        self.listaDatosPublico.place(x=175, y=210)
        self.scroll1.place(x=190, y=210)
        
        
        
        #Texto para el mes
        self.labelMes = tk.Label(self.ventana2,text='Mes/Meses')
        self.labelMes.place(x=20,y=330)
        #Cuadro de texto para mostrar los meses del año
        self.scroll2 = tk.Scrollbar(self.ventana2, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.listaMesesPublico = tk.Listbox(self.ventana2, width=30, height=4,selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE,
                                            yscrollcommand=self.scroll2.set)
        self.scroll2.configure(command=self.listaMesesPublico.yview) 
        self.listaMesesPublico.place(x=175, y=330)
        self.scroll2.place(x=190, y=330)
        
        # Cuadro de texto para mostrar el resumen de los datos ingresados
        self.texto = tk.Text(self.ventana2, height=5, width=40, wrap='word')
        self.texto.insert(tk.END, "")
        self.texto.config(state='disabled')  # Configurar el widget como solo lectura
        self.texto.place(x=90,y=420)
        
        
        


Tienes que establecer el argumento exportselection en False para ambos listbox. Generalmente, por defecto el texto seleccionado en un widgets es exportado al gestor de ventanas. De la documentación de tk (traducción libre):

exportselection
Especifica si una selección en el widget debe ser también la selección
X. El valor puede tener cualquiera de las formas aceptadas por
Tcl_GetBoolean, como true, false, 0, 1, yes o no. Si la
selección se exporta, entonces seleccionar en el widget deselecciona
la selección X actual, seleccionar fuera del widget deselecciona
cualquier selección del widget, y el widget responderá a las
peticiones de recuperación de selección cuando tenga una selección.
Por defecto, los widgets suelen exportar las selecciones.

Con "selección X" se refiere a la selección primaria (PRIMARY selection) del sistema de ventanas X (X11). La selección primaria es única, el búffer solo contiene la última selección realizada por el usuario, en cuanto selecciones algo en otro widgets de la app la selección anterior se pierde. Si no exportas la selección de tus widgets ésta se mantendrá en cada uno.
    self.listaDatosPublico = tk.Listbox(
        self.ventana2, width=30, height=4, selectmode=tk.SINGLE,
        yscrollcommand=self.scroll1.set, exportselection=False
    )


    # ....

    self.listaMesesPublico = tk.Listbox(
        self.ventana2, width=30, height=4, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE,
        yscrollcommand=self.scroll2.set, exportselection=False
    )

Esta respuesta de Bryan Oakley lo explica en una pregunta similar en SO.
Un ejemplo reproducible simplificado:
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

meses_var = tk.Variable(value=("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"))
mes_list = tk.Listbox(
    root, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, listvariable=meses_var, exportselect=False
)
mes_list.pack()

dias_var = tk.Variable(value=("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
dias_list = tk.Listbox(
    root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, listvariable=dias_var, exportselect=False
)
dias_list.pack()

def imprimir_seleccion():
    print(f"\nMes: {''.join(map(mes_list.get, mes_list.curselection()))}")
    print(f"Dias: {', '.join(map(dias_list.get, dias_list.curselection()))}")
    
tk.Button(root, text="Imprimir selección", command=imprimir_seleccion).pack()

root.mainloop()


Muchas gracias, eso me resolvió mi problema y ya pude continuar con mi código
